# Do a curl request in Java

Tags: java, api, curl

What is the correct way of making a curl request using Java?

I am trying to fetch data from an API. When I run from my command prompt in Windows

```
curl "https://api.b365api.com/v3/bet365/prematch?token=YOUR_TOKEN&FI=120986569"
```

I get a JSON response back. But when I try with different kind of ways I do not get any response back. The page only have code samples for PHP Python and Perl
https://betsapi.com/docs/others/code_samples.html

The same api is available from rapidapi where they have code snippets like:

```
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://betsapi2.p.rapidapi.com/v3/bet365/prematch?FI=120986569"))
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "YOUR_KEY")
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "betsapi2.p.rapidapi.com")
            .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.body());
```

When I try using these I does not work either. Does anyone have any thoughts that can help me?

Edit: Sorry for unclear info.
The request is done and no error are thrown. But I do not get the response body. It seems to be empty.
But when I debug and steps thru I can see the body response in the debug window but it is not printed out on the console.

Update/Solution:
Tried the following code:

```
String url = "https://api.betsapi.com/v3/bet365/prematch?token=YOURTOKEN&FI=120986569";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println("StatusCode: " + response.code());
System.out.println("BodyResponse: " + response.body().string());
```

> StatusCode: 200

As you can see it is not printing out "BodyResponse: " which it should do in my opinion. When I mark and copy the data from the console the json response are there but I can´t see it in the console.
So when I copy the console response to an editor I see the following:

> StatusCode: 200 BodyResponse:
> {"success":1,"results":[{"FI":"120986569","event_id":"5164182","asian_lines":{"updated_at":"1659507064","key".......
> and it continues..

So it is working but I couldn´t actually see the response in the console.

Comment: You need to explain "does not work".

Comment: Thank you @accessviolation. I have updated with some more info in the end.

Comment: What is response.statusCode()?  You need to know whether the request worked before looking at the content of the response.

Comment: Are you supplying a valid key? Without a valid key, the request returns `HTTP response code: 403 Forbidden`.

Comment: @accessviolation statusCode = 200 which tells me that it was OK. When I the request in debug mode I can see in the debug window that response = "correct json response" but it is not printed out. Can it be that everything happens to fast somehow so the console print out before everything is finished?

Comment: @AndrWeisR yes I am providing a valid key. I have just "masked" it now since I do not want to share it public. The statuscode = 200 which tells me it went ok. When I the request in debug mode I can see in the debug window that response = "correct json response" but it is not printed out. Can it be that everything happens to fast somehow so the console print out before everything is finished?

Comment: @accessviolation I found out that it seems to have been working all the time. But it is not printed out in the console which I do not understand. As you can see in my updated text I can copy the text from the console and then paste itin an editor. Then the response are visible for me. Do you have any idea why? The response are really long. The response are 78114 signs long.

Comment: You can ''copy' from the console but you can't see the text in the console?  Sounds odd.  What is this console, anyway?  An IDE like VScode, or a plain old console window running the cmd processor?

Comment: Currently I am using Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)  Build id: 20211202-1639 and console I mean the console window in the IDE.

Comment: I would check your console preferences in Eclipse - i.e. Run/Debug -> Console. Maybe untick "Limit console output" if it's ticked.

Comment: @AndrWeisR thank you for your assistance. I noticed that if I saved the json response to a string and the printed out the string I actually got the response printed in the console.

String response = response.body().string();
System.out.println(response);